# Бинпоиск по set с++

Tags: c++, set

Можно ли в c++ реализовать бинпоиск по сету?

Comment: Простите уж, но это из серии "нельзя ли при поездке на велосипеде крутить педали?" :) - он же и так именно такой...

Comment: Нет. Классический бинарный поиск требует структуры данных с произвольным доступом. `std::set` таковой не является.

Answer (score 2):

`std::set::lower_bound` делает бинарный поиск. И все остальные функции, в т.ч. `count` тоже, потому что оно сортированное.